# How to append the values in checkbox in jquery AJAX response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here I using two ajax,both ajax return the success response like **response** and **result** based on the success message I want to apppen the values in form field, from here first ajax is working fine but second ajax response I am not able to append the values in **check box** I am trying like this but I did n't get any thing (checkbox not appending)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.example.com/api/get/properties/586caa3505dd7b13789e02a8', 
 type: 'GET',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 success: function (data) {
  
   var htmlString='';
   
   var response = {"name":"3 BHK APARTMENT FOR SALE","email":"abcd@gmail.com"}
  
    htmlString+='<form class="form-horizontal" id="post_property_edit_form"><div class="row">';
    htmlString+='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><h4><a style="color:#325d88;;text-decoration:none;">Property Details</a></h4></div></div>';
    htmlString+='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="name" style="font-weight: bold;">Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control align2" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" style="" value="'+response.name+'"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="email" class="form-control align2" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" style="" value="'+response.email+'" readonly=""></div></div><div class="col-md-1"></div></div>';
  
   
    $.ajax({
   //headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+token},
   url: 'http://www.example.com/api/get/property-types', 
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (result) {
    console.log(result); 
    var result1 = [ {
       "id" : "57fde39205dd7b0ef89e02e3",
       "name" : "Apartment",
       "propertyPurpose" : {
      "id" : "57cfe071fb47b70f3b147c66",
      "name" : "RESIDENTIAL",
      "description" : "Residential purpose"
       },
       "description" : "Residential Property Type"
     }, {
       "id" : "57fde3aa05dd7b0ef89e02e4",
       "name" : "Villament",
       "propertyPurpose" : {
      "id" : "57cfe071fb47b70f3b147c66",
      "name" : "RESIDENTIAL",
      "description" : "Residential purpose"
       },
       "description" : "Residential Property Type"
     }
     ]
     $.each( result1, function( key, p_typevalue ) {
     
     htmlString+='<input type="checkbox" value="'+p_typevalue.name+'" id="property_typsdfsde" >'+p_typevalue.name;
    });
    
   },
   error: function (errMsg) {
    console.log(errMsg);
   }
  });  
   
   //htmlString+='<input type="checkbox" name="dssd" id="property_typsdfsde" >ddsfsdfsdf';
   
 
   htmlString+='<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;"><p style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;width:100px;border-radius: 0px;">Submit</button></p></div></div></form>'; 
 
 $('.post_property_edit').empty().append(htmlString); 
 },
 error: function (errMsg) {
  console.log(errMsg);
 }
});
});
```

```html
<!-- POST PROPERTY EDIT-->
<div class="post_property_edit"></div>
<!-- POST PROPERTY EDIT-->
```

Comment: render first element on page and continue render success on first element step by step, 'htmlString' not work in second $.ajax.

Answer (score 0):

You can create an div element as a container in the 1st ajax response and use it in the 2nd ajax request

will say we are creating div element with the class "check-box-container"
Add this line to end of the 1st ajax response htmlString

```
<div class='check-box-container'></div>
```

and user it in 2nd ajax response as bellow

$('.check-box-container').append(2nd_Response_htmlStingr);

Think this might helps you to get an idea

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried out .append function sometime it will help

This is one of my example how I achieved append

```
function editLeavePolicyDetails(id) {


var removeLeaveTypeDetails=0;

$.ajax({
    url: '/ajax-leave-policy/' + id,
    data: {
        format: 'json'
    },
    dataType: 'json',

    type: 'GET',
    success: function (data) {
        console.log('loadedData',data);
        //console.log(data[2][0][0]);

        //$('.field.validation-error').empty();
        //$('.error').text('');

        //loadingPolicyDetails();


        $('#leavePolicyEditModal').on('hidden.bs.modal', function ()
        {
            $(this).find("textarea,select").val('').end();

            validator.resetForm();

            //hide();

            //deleting loaded details


            console.log(leaveTypeCount);
            while (removeLeaveTypeDetails > 0) {
                $('#editLeaveType'+ (removeLeaveTypeDetails-1)).remove();
                $('#editNoOfDays'+ (removeLeaveTypeDetails-1)).remove();
                //$('#space'+ (No-1)).remove();
                removeLeaveTypeDetails--;
            }


        });

        leaveTypeCount = data[4];
        console.log('leaveTypeCount',leaveTypeCount);
        var x;

        $('#Tid0').val(id);
        $('#Tid2').val(data[3][0]);

        //loading details

        for (x = 0; x < leaveTypeCount; x++) {

            var type = data[2][x][0];
            var days = data[1][x][0];


            var $cloneTypeID = $('<input />', {
                'id': 'editLeaveType' + x,
                'value': type,
                //'class':'col-sm-6 left',
                'name': 'Leave_Type' + x,
                'required': "enter",
                'disabled':true

            });

            var $space = $('</br>', {
                'id':'space'+x
            });

            var $cloneDaysID = $('<input />', {
                'id': 'editNoOfDays' + x,
                'value': days,
                //'class':'col-sm-6 right',
                'name': 'No_of_Days' + x


            });

            $('#xx').append($cloneTypeID);
            document.getElementById("#xx").disabled = true;
            $('#xx1').append($cloneDaysID);


        }
        removeLeaveTypeDetails=leaveTypeCount;

        console.log('removeLeaveTypeDetails',removeLeaveTypeDetails);

        $("#leavePolicyEditModal").modal('show');


    },
    error: function () {
        $('#info').html('<p>An error has occurred</p>');
    }

});
```

This is one of my own example hope you can get some thing out of it.

If you need further clarification just buzz in

Answer (score 0):

Put this code above in second ajax success method:

```
htmlString+='<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;"><p style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;width:100px;border-radius: 0px;">Submit</button></p></div></div></form>'; 

$('.post_property_edit').html(htmlString);
```

Correct Code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
 url: 'http://www.example.com/api/get/properties/586caa3505dd7b13789e02a8', 
 type: 'GET',
 contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
 success: function (data) {
  
   var htmlString='';
   
   var response = {"name":"3 BHK APARTMENT FOR SALE","email":"abcd@gmail.com"}
  
    htmlString+='<form class="form-horizontal" id="post_property_edit_form"><div class="row">';
    htmlString+='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-4"><h4><a style="color:#325d88;;text-decoration:none;">Property Details</a></h4></div></div>';
    htmlString+='<div class="row"><div class="col-md-1"></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="name" style="font-weight: bold;">Name:</label><input type="name" class="form-control align2" id="name" placeholder="Enter Name" style="" value="'+response.name+'"></div></div><div class="col-md-2"></div><div class="col-md-4"><div class="form-group"><label class="control-label" for="email">Email Address:</label><input type="email" class="form-control align2" id="email" placeholder="Enter Email Address" style="" value="'+response.email+'" readonly=""></div></div><div class="col-md-1"></div></div>';
  
   
    $.ajax({
   //headers: {"Authorization": "Bearer "+token},
   url: 'http://www.example.com/api/get/property-types', 
   type: 'GET',
   contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
   success: function (result) {
    console.log(result); 
    var result1 = [ {
       "id" : "57fde39205dd7b0ef89e02e3",
       "name" : "Apartment",
       "propertyPurpose" : {
      "id" : "57cfe071fb47b70f3b147c66",
      "name" : "RESIDENTIAL",
      "description" : "Residential purpose"
       },
       "description" : "Residential Property Type"
     }, {
       "id" : "57fde3aa05dd7b0ef89e02e4",
       "name" : "Villament",
       "propertyPurpose" : {
      "id" : "57cfe071fb47b70f3b147c66",
      "name" : "RESIDENTIAL",
      "description" : "Residential purpose"
       },
       "description" : "Residential Property Type"
     }
     ]
     $.each( result1, function( key, p_typevalue ) {
     
     htmlString+='<input type="checkbox" value="'+p_typevalue.name+'" id="property_typsdfsde" >'+p_typevalue.name;
    });
   //==========================================================
   //start - code in here
   //==========================================================

   htmlString+='<div class="row" style="margin-top:50px;"><p style="text-align:center;"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success" style="padding-top: 6px; padding-bottom: 6px;width:100px;border-radius: 0px;">Submit</button></p></div></div></form>'; 
 
   $('.post_property_edit').html(htmlString); 
   //========================================================
   //end - code in here
   //========================================================
   },
   error: function (errMsg) {
    console.log(errMsg);
   }
  });  
   
  
   
 
  
 },
 error: function (errMsg) {
  console.log(errMsg);
 }
});
});
```

```html
<!-- POST PROPERTY EDIT-->
<div class="post_property_edit"></div>
<!-- POST PROPERTY EDIT-->
```

Comment: Mr Chiarato, i tried ur code i am getting error possible means update fiddle

Comment: Your code working but y you are making inside tha ajax you closed suppose i want to use one more Ajax means where i have to start and where i have to finish

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code on my machine i got your ajax directly goes to error function not in success part.
first of all your api is not returning any kind of json and you are trying to get response in json by define contentType json that's why your ajax directly goes to error function.
**var response** and **var result1** is hard coded json by you not a response which should be come from ajax call.

And one more issue about url i got in console.

**Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://www.example.com/api/get/properties/586caa3505dd7b13789e02a8. This can be fixed by moving the resource to the same domain or enabling CORS.**